# CSS help needed, I need to stack circular divs under each other

Tags: css

I have a circular div with a some css that makes it expand on mousover. I have no idea on how to start about making another bigger circle sit behind it with the same center point. This could create a ring around the first circle.

e.g. with each green ring representing the outside of the next circle (3 circles in total)

[image: http://2.bp.blogspot.com/_HoDij8Z2tHY/TJzb854jDVI/AAAAAAAAEv4/dMzvpjkq8XI/s1600/concentric_circles1.jpg]

an image example

I don't think i explained it very well! :/ Sorry! I need separate divs, not one that makes a outer ring!

Here is my current code:

```css
#circles
{
margin-right:auto;
margin-left:auto;
width:800px;
height:800px;
alignment-adjust:central;
}

.circle1
{position:relative;

margin-top:50%;
margin-right:auto;
margin-left:auto;
width:100px;
height:100px;
border-radius:50%;
background: #ff3019; /* Old browsers */
background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #ff3019 0%, #cf0404 100%); /* FF3.6+ */
background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,#ff3019), color-stop(100%,#cf0404)); /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #ff3019 0%,#cf0404 100%); /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #ff3019 0%,#cf0404 100%); /* Opera 11.10+ */
background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #ff3019 0%,#cf0404 100%); /* IE10+ */
background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #ff3019 0%,#cf0404 100%); /* W3C */  

transition:1s;
-moz-transition: 1s; /* Firefox 4 */
-webkit-transition: 1s; /* Safari and Chrome */
-o-transition: 1s; /* Opera */
-ms-transition: 1s; /* IE9 (maybe) */

}
```

Comment: you'd need to adjust the top/left of each cirle by the radius of the circle. e.g. if the red dot is at 100,100, and the first small circle has a radius of 10, then its top/left needs to 90,90, then 80,80, then 70,70, etc...

Comment: HTML/JS? Can you make a jsfiddle with what you have

Comment: have you considered using SVG or Canvas instead?

Answer (score 2):

do you mean that you want them to grow on hover , like circles in water ?
http://jsfiddle.net/GCyrillus/jGtAv/1

nested div with padding should do it or span .

```
div {
    min-height:1em;
    min-width:1em;
    margin:0;
    box-shadow:inset 0 0 0 1px;
    border-radius:100%;
    transition:1s;
    display:inline-block;
    vertical-align:top;
    text-align:center;line-height:0.8em;text-shadow:0 0 5px
}
div:hover, div:hover div {
    padding:3em;
    transition:1s;
}
```

```
   <div id="ring" title="rings in water"">
        <div>
            <div>
                <div>
                    <div>
                        <div>
                            <div>
                                <div id="stone"> o </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: same with  more box-shadows to it http://jsfiddle.net/GCyrillus/jGtAv/2

Answer (score 1):

Something like that?

@GCyrillus has nested i have separate divs...

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
 <head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>circles</title>
  <style>
   html,body{margin:0;padding:0;}
   body>div>div{
    position:fixed;
    border-radius:100%;
    border:1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
    width:250px;
    height:250px;
    -webkit-transition:all 1200ms ease;
   }
   body>div>div:nth-child(1){-webkit-transform:scale(0.3);}
   body>div>div:nth-child(2){-webkit-transform:scale(0.3);}
   body>div>div:nth-child(3){-webkit-transform:scale(0.3);}
   body>div:hover>div:nth-child(1){-webkit-transform:scale(1);}
   body>div:hover>div:nth-child(2){-webkit-transform:scale(0.8);}
   body>div:hover>div:nth-child(3){-webkit-transform:scale(0.6);}
  </style>
 </head>
 <body>
  <div>
   <div></div>
   <div></div>
   <div></div>
  </div>
 </body>
</html>
```