# CSS, stacking circles

Tags: css

I want to make some circular divs like the one in my code below. However I want them stacked behind each other, so i would want a blue circle (that expands) behind the current red one, but centered the same as the red one. The red one needs to be on top.

Here is my current code:

```
#circles
{
margin-right:auto;
margin-left:auto;
width:800px;
height:800px;
alignment-adjust:central;
}

.circle1
{position:relative;

margin-top:50%;
margin-right:auto;
margin-left:auto;
width:100px;
height:100px;
border-radius:50%;
background: #ff3019; /* Old browsers */
background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #ff3019 0%, #cf0404 100%); /* FF3.6+ */
background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,#ff3019), color-stop(100%,#cf0404)); /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #ff3019 0%,#cf0404 100%); /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #ff3019 0%,#cf0404 100%); /* Opera 11.10+ */
background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #ff3019 0%,#cf0404 100%); /* IE10+ */
background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #ff3019 0%,#cf0404 100%); /* W3C */  

transition:1s;
-moz-transition: 1s; /* Firefox 4 */
-webkit-transition: 1s; /* Safari and Chrome */
-o-transition: 1s; /* Opera */
-ms-transition: 1s; /* IE9 (maybe) */

}
```

Comment: Why the downvotes on this question? I think it's a good one.

Comment: Please include a JS Fiddle for code like this, it's hard to understand what you have now.

Comment: How is this different from your last question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16966858/css-help-needed-i-need-to-stack-circular-divs-under-each-other?

Comment: He posted his CSS. The HTML has some divs with class="circle1,2,3" He's using border radius to make circles. He wants them stacked and centered with the blue one behind and getting bigger than the red one.

Comment: HTML is kinda obvious in this case by looking at the CSS, just sayin.

Comment: @j08691 It's not the second question, it's the third (and one more a little bit different)

Comment: I added the question again, however I reworded it as It was difficult to understand what I meant! I did edit my first but got no answers after the edit so reposted, but that was confusing also! But second answer is what I wanted!! I'll work out how to make them both expand!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check this jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ZTMxz/

Is this what you were looking for?

Here is the code:

```
#circles
{
margin-right:auto;
margin-left:auto;
width:800px;
height:800px;
alignment-adjust:central;
}

.circle1
{position:relative;

margin-top:50%;
margin-right:auto;
margin-left:auto;
width:100px;
height:100px;
border-radius:50%;
background: #ff3019; /* Old browsers */
background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #ff3019 0%, #cf0404 100%); /* FF3.6+ */
background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,#ff3019), color-stop(100%,#cf0404)); /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #ff3019 0%,#cf0404 100%); /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #ff3019 0%,#cf0404 100%); /* Opera 11.10+ */
background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #ff3019 0%,#cf0404 100%); /* IE10+ */
background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #ff3019 0%,#cf0404 100%); /* W3C */  

transition:1s;
-moz-transition: 1s; /* Firefox 4 */
-webkit-transition: 1s; /* Safari and Chrome */
-o-transition: 1s; /* Opera */
-ms-transition: 1s; /* IE9 (maybe) */
z-index: 2;

}
.circle2
{position:relative;

margin-top:50%;
margin-right:auto;
margin-left:auto;
width:140px;
height:140px;
border-radius:50%;
background: #ff3019; /* Old browsers */
background: -moz-linear-gradient(top,  #b8d8f2 0%, #92bde0 100%); /* FF3.6+ */
background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%, #b8c7f2), color-stop(100%,#92bde0)); /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top,  #b8d8f2 0%,#92bde0 100%); /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
background: -o-linear-gradient(top,  #b8d8f2 0%,#92bde0 100%); /* Opera 11.10+ */
background: -ms-linear-gradient(top,  #b8d8f2 0%,#92bde0 100%); /* IE10+ */
background: linear-gradient(to bottom,  #b8d8f2 0%,#92bde0 100%); /* W3C */  

transition:1s;
-moz-transition: 1s; /* Firefox 4 */
-webkit-transition: 1s; /* Safari and Chrome */
-o-transition: 1s; /* Opera */
-ms-transition: 1s; /* IE9 (maybe) */
z-index: 1;
margin-top: -15%;

}
```

Comment: The circle don't expand now? I have looked at it and I don't understand why!

Comment: Also they are offline for me?

Comment: Here is an example where the blue circle expands when you hover on the red one: http://jsfiddle.net/cEZKE/ . Is this what you were looking for? If not in what circumstances you want that circle to expand? On page load?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this would be a bit easier:

```
.circle {
  width: 140px;
  height: 140px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: blue;
}

.circle:before {
  position: relative;
  top: 20px;
  left: 20px;
  display: block;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: red;
  content: "";
}
```